# How to query only objects containing each element from the array given as a variable using Hasura?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, hasura

I have a table 'Students' in my db(postgress with Hasura) with relation many-to-many with 'Subjects':

```js
type Student = {
    id: uuid
    name: String
    subjects: [subject]
}

type Subject = {
    id: uuid
    name: String
}
```

I have a **Static QUERY1**:

```
query FilteredStudents($subjects: [String!]) {
    students(where: { subjects: { name: { _in: $subjects } } }) {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

e.g.:

```
$subjects = ['Math', 'English', 'Physics']
```

It will find all the students that attend to **ANY** of those classes.
e.g.:

```
const student1 = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Mike',
   subjects: ['Physics', 'Chemistry']  // subjects mapped to names for simplicity
}
```

My problem is that I want another query which will find all the students that attend to **EACH** of those classes.

So it shouldn't fetch **student1**, but should fetch students like this:

```
const student2 = {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Walt',
   subjects: ['Math', 'English', 'Physics', 'Some', 'other', 'subjects']  // subjects mapped to names for simplicity
}
```

My only idea was to create dynamic queries like this:
**Dynamic QUERY2** (a new query is generated (on **runtime**) every time the $subject array changes):

```
query FilteredStudents {
    students(where: { _and: [
        subjects: { name: { _eq: "Math" } }
        subjects: { name: { _eq: "English" } } 
        subjects: { name: { _eq: "Physics" } } 
    ]}) {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

But I would really want to avoid that and find some static solution. Is there a way to achieve this using filters offered by Hasura? (https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html#)

Comment: Ugh, I can't figure this one out. The two options I can think of are both not super good.

1. Get all users like you are in `Query 1` and then filter them on the client

2. Add all of the relationships to a `hasSubjects` JSON column and then filter like this https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html#jsonb-operators-contains-has-key-etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can name your QUERY2 as static already and QUERY1 as dynamic - 1st is parametrized, 2nd is hardcoded.

You can construct and pass as variable entire `where` object for both.

You can read [this](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/query-filters.html#fetch-if-all-of-the-nested-objects-defined-via-an-array-relationship-satisfy-a-condition) and use `_not` with `_nin` to do the same (as '_and' usage). It stil will be a dynamic condition because **`where` is an input type** ... and almost the same condition object creation complexity.

### update

```
const subset = ['Math', 'English'];

const condition = { _and: [] };
subset.map( el => {
  condition._and.push( {
    subjects: { name: { _eq: el } } 
  });
});

callSomeLazyQuery( { variables: {
  where: condition 
} );
```

the same should be valid

```
const condition = {
  _not: { 
    _and: [] 
  }
};
subset.map( el => {
  condition._not._and.push( {
    subjects: { name: { _nil: el } } 
  });
});
```

Comment: I called QUERY1 static because it is hardcoded - i can only manipulate variables passed to this query. The QUERY2 is only an example of query generated on **runtime**, so I need to generate a new query every time the $subject array changes - that's why I called it dynamic. 

About the solution with `_not` and `_nin` - already tried that, but it matches **only** students that have exactly the same subjects I pass to it. For `$subjects=['Math', 'German']` it will return students with only these subjects, but I would like to get also students with e.g.: `["Math", "German", "Chemistry"]`.

Comment: hardcoded by who? generated by who? queries shouldn't be generated - it's a bad practise (like manipulating strings to glue SQL query) ... on server mutation expects only one argument for `where` and your app should create and pass as variable this one param

Comment: `_not` and `_nin` should work, maybe `_not` `_and` `_nin`? - test step by step, `_nin` alone ... if you're sure it should work prepare proof [example] and file an issue? .... anyway - you can use already working `_and` `_eq`

Comment: hardcoded - by me, generated by function (on runtime). Yeah, I believe it is a bad practice that's why I ask if there is a better solution. I would like to use simple `where` but it seems there is no simple solution (or I can't find one). 
I just showed you why `_not` and `_nin` won't work. Guessing which combination of `_not` `_and` `_nin` might work is terrible approach. 
_"you can use already working _and _eq"_ - that's pretty bold assumption, any ideas how such a query could look like? because I came up with nothing.

Comment: see updated answer ... logical combinations can be decomposed and checked step by step during rebuild (you can check single _nin, two _nin's with _and and negation of single _nin etc.), it's not terrible ;)

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for, I didn't know that I can pass a whole `where` (of the type `BoolExp`) as the parameter of a query.